# VBA subtraction for multiple table values

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am writing Excel VBA code. I just wanted to do subtraction for this kind of table

[image: cash - spending for all of the items]

But I can't figure out how to do that using VBA. Is the code below correct?

```
Sub OperationO()

    Dim OE As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 3 To Range("F6")
        Cells(6, i).Value = Cells(2, i).Value - Cells(4, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really use formulas for something like this, but if you insists on VBA, here it goes.

Whenever you write code for VBA or any similar languages, read what you are writing, what it should/needs to do, as you read it out loud many times the errors pop up. Think of the comments below as "me reading as I write."

```
Sub OperationO()
    'Initiate a Variable type Integer for number storage
    Dim OE as Integer
    'Initiate another variable same type to use in the loop
    Dim i as Integer
    'Start a loop from 3 to 6 (because these are the columns you are working with)
    For i = 3 to 6
        'Set the value in Column "i" on Row 6 to the value in Row 2 minus Row 4 in the same column
        'Now here is the thing, when you subtract a negative number, you are adding it, crazy math rules i know, so if the number is negative, you need to Add instead.
        Cells(6, i).Value = (Cells(2, i).Value + Cells(4, i).Value)
        'If both cells don't contain a number, this will fail, additional checks may help, like IsNumber
    Next i
'Its the end of the Sub and you never used the Variable OE, it was declared for nothing.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind advice and solution!